# Show that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \infty$ and $a_n\in[0,1]$, then $\lim_{k \to \infty} \prod_{n=1}^k (1- a_n) = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $0 \leq a_n \leq 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, show that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \infty$, then $\lim_{k \to \infty} \prod_{n=1}^k (1- a_n) = 0$.

I found this statement in a proof of the Borel-Cantelli lemma which I do not know how to verify, any hint or help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is obviously false.

Comment: If you take $a_{n}=3$ for each $n$, your statement does not hold. You need some other conditions as well. However, if each $a_{n}$ is contained in $[0,1)$, then it does indeed hold.

Comment: @DeanMiller Yes, you are correct. I edited my question.

Comment: You may use the inequality $$0\leq 1-x \leq e^{-x}$$ which holds for all $x \leq 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the limit of the products always exists as it is a limit of a decreasing sequence of nonnegative real numbers.

Suppose $\lim_{k\to\infty}\prod_{n=1}^{k}(1-a_{n}) > 0$. For each $k\in\mathbb{N}$, set $p_{k} = \prod_{n=1}^{k}(1-a_{n})$. If $p = \lim_{k\to\infty}p_{k}$, then $p>0$ by assumption.

For $x\in [0,1]$, the inequality $e^{-x}\geq 1-x$ is valid. As a result, $x\leq -\log (1-x)$ for such $x$. Then for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$, the following estimate is valid:

$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{k}a_{n} \leq -\sum_{n=1}^{k}\log (1-a_{n}) \leq -\log (p_{k}) \leq -\log (p)$$

So the partial sums are bounded and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ converges.

Consequently, if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}=\infty$, then the infinite product of the $1-a_{n}$ terms must be zero.